# Why is Condenser energy guide rating different from advertised?

Tags: hvac, energy-efficiency

I'm installing a Carrier 24APB6 which has advertised up to 17 SEER. The seller tells me it is a 16 SEER unit but the yellow Energy Guide sticker on the condenser gives it a SEER rating of 14 on a 13-26 scale. The sales person tells me I will be seeing SEER 16 performance. What is the actual SEER of the unit? Did I buy a 14 SEER unit thinking I was getting a 16 SEER unit?

[image]

Here is my horizontal R410A coil:
[image]

Comment: I just asked a similar question [on Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/10639/3379). It's A/C installation season!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Depending on your furnace, this combination is either 15 or 16 SEER.**

Using the [product type search](https://www.ahridirectory.org/NewSearch?programId=68&searchTypeId=3&productTypeId=3500) on the AHRI website (recommended by [@MonkeyZeus](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/227882/86548)), I entered these parameters:

- Outdoor unit model number: `24APB636A`
- Indoor unit model number: `PL36H210P74`

The search ignores later parts of the model numbers. This returns 51 results, of which 10 have SEER 15, while the rest are SEER 16. You could enter your furnace model number to know for sure (assuming your particular combination has been tested), but odds are your combination is 16 SEER.

> [image: AHRI search results]

Comment: Would you know why the energy guide rating is at 14 SEER? Is that a lower bound for that component?

Comment: @simgineer the Energy Guide seems designed to confuse. For your outdoor unit model number, there are 4,452 combinations with SEER ratings ranging from 12 to 18. You can then see the Energy Guide labels for specific combinations, and the dozen or so I checked all say 14. I think they'd be better off without it, to be honest.

Comment: @simgineer down the rabbit hole, from Federal Regulations, [10 CFR 430](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=f752da64eebff2d043228033936d5aae&mc=true&n=pt10.3.430&r=PART&ty=HTML): "split-systems—air conditioners that are installed [...] in the States of Alabama, Arkansas, Delaware, Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maryland, Mississippi, North Carolina, Oklahoma, South Carolina, Tennessee, Texas, or Virginia, or in the District of Columbia, must have a Seasonal Energy Efficiency Ratio (SEER) of 14 or higher."

Comment: @simgineer similar to vehicle mpg ratings, even if you don't live in one of those states I wouldn't be surprised if manufacturers just build all systems to meet that requirement to keep things simpler and get better economies of scale.

Answer (score 4):

You need to match it with the proper evaporator coil, TXV valve, and furnace model in order to achieve that 17 SEER rating.

Visit https://www.ahridirectory.org/Search/SearchHome and search for `201506361`. That is the equipment I recently installed to achieve 18 SEER.

Comment: I thought that was a comment, I suggested an answer,  I was going to say the same thing. All the pieces have to work together at a high level to get the best efficiency an example would be an orifice instead of the throttle valve (txv) would only have 13-14 seer a inside coil with more or finer fins exchanges heat better so the active valve and quality coil on the evaporator bring it to the max that unit can provide. To get even higher a fancier condenser coil in the outside unit and an inverter driven compressor  can get to the 20’s in some cases but each item costs $

Comment: @EdBeal It **was** a comment =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same scenario on a Payne "16 SEER" whose website claims it can get to 17 SEER, but the yellow tag claims 14 SEER.  Carrier claims all the components must work together to achieve 16, but the outside unit also works with 14.  In short, the unit truly is a '16 SEER' with a lot of caveats.  So apparently the yellow tag is simply a minimum standard.

Comment: That does not sound correct, are all the same model. If so then if you buy one get the SEER rating in writing with a warranty it will meet or exceed that rating.